# Show highcharts for database data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have tried to display a chart for database data but I'm having some trouble. I've tried using json to high charts but it's not working. Could someone please explain to me how to show axis as date and to call this on viewpage?

```
public List<CustomerAccount> ChartData(long customerID)
{
    List<CustomerAccount> chart = new List<CustomerAccount>();

    List<CustomerAccount> points = new CustomerAccountDBMgr().ChartAccount(customerID).FindAll(e => e.AccountName != "Others");
    if (null == points || points.Count == 0)
        return null;

    var val = (from item in points select new { CreatedAt = item.CreatedAt, OpeningBalance = item.OpeningBalance }).ToList();

    foreach (var data in val)
    {
        CustomerAccount objCustomer = new CustomerAccount()
        {
            CreatedAt = data.CreatedAt,
            OpeningBalance = data.OpeningBalance
        };
        chart.Add(objCustomer);
     }
     return chart;
 }
```

Model

```
public class Chart1
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public Double? OpeningBalance { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerAccount> ChartData()
    { 
        PersonalizeBL business=new PersonalizeBL();
        var CustomerID = PERFICSSession.GetCustomerID();
        List<CustomerAccount>point=business.ChartData(CustomerID);
        return point;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Chart1()
{
    if (!PERFICSSession.IsValidSession())
        return View("Login");

    Chart1 model = new Chart1();

    Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Database Data" })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Type = AxisTypes.Datetime })
    .SetYAxis(new[]
    {
        new YAxis
        {
            Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Amount" },
            GridLineWidth = 1
        }
    })
    .SetSeries(new[]
    {
        new Series
        {
            Name = "OpeningBalance",
            Data = new Data((model.ChartData()).Select(x=>new points{X=DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Tools.GetTotalMilliseconds(x.CreatedAt),Y=x.OpeningBalance}).ToArray())
        }
    });

    return View("Chart1");
}
```

Comment: [This topic](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/454622) may help.

Comment: Thanks Mr.pawel but I cant navigate high chart from controller to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answere for this issue. i would have return view which object i did created from highcharts. i wrongly returned the view page name.

```
 public ActionResult Chart1()
        {
            chartModel model = new chartModel();
            var data = model.chartPlots(Session);

            Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Database Data" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Type = AxisTypes.Datetime })
            .SetYAxis(new[]
                      {
                          new YAxis
                          {
                              Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Amount" },
                              GridLineWidth = 1
                          }
            })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                       {
                           new Series
                           {
                               Name = "OpeningBalance",
                               Data = new Data(data.Select(x=>new points{X=DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Tools.GetTotalMilliseconds(x.CreatedAt),Y=x.OpeningBalance}).ToArray())
                           }
                       });

            return View(chart);
        }

 return View(chart);
}
```